# How restrict cloud storage PC applications to access other than "home" folders?

Tags: windows, dropbox, google-drive, cloud-storage, privacy-protection

There is many cloud storage services like Google Drive, OneDrive, Dropbox, iDrive, etc. which install own companion application on PC to easy access their services from computer desktop.
This applications:

1. usualy uploads/downloads huge amount of data
2. and must have granted internet access (firewall rules off)

So in fact there isn't known if these apps uploads only files from their specified "home" (shared) folder or - an example - access and upload all files from *My Documents* or *My Photos* or any other private folder from the disk.
Of course I could use some access monitoring tools from e.g. Sysinternals to check if these apps access any files or folders outside of their specified sharing folder - but this is inconvenient to permanently stare at file access logs.

So I wonder if there is a way to restrict for these apps access on Windows to only specified files and folders on a disk?

Comment: To some extent you have to trust the people that wrote these apps. One possibility would be to have a special machine with the cloud apps and you used a service to transfer files to that machine and its special folders or you hand carried with a thumb drive.

Comment: This is a non-problem. It's your imagination at work only. If any of those services did what you're afraid of, that would be known by now in the media and it would be a huge scandal!

Comment: “So in fact there isn't known if these apps uploads only files from their specified "home" (shared) folder“ - I know for a fact they only upload files you place in the specified folder. Stop worrying about a fictional problem

Comment: Maybe it is _fictional_ or _imaginative_ problem, but this question remains more generic in its core - how restrict application access to folders other than specified?